# Auto Complete email address field when name is selected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi all I'm using this code for a datalist tag dropdown field to select a name and email from a list or allows for new name or email to be inserted (thanks Tanaike) that works great.
I was wondering if someone could help me with the code to auto populate the email field if the selected name exist. The name list is from my Google sheet DD column 'B' and the email are in column 'C'
here's the code I'm using. The way it workimg now I'm able to select the email but I would like it to auto populate.
Thanks

```
<!--------------- Name Select ------------------->
      <script>
                    function namedd() {
                    var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
                    console.log(value)
                    }
                  </script>

                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                      <label for="name">name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="input" class="form-control" list="name" name="name" placeholder="Select name" >
                      <datalist id="name"  >
                     <?
                      var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DD");
                      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
                      var myRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B"+lastRow);
                      var data    = myRange.getValues();
                      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
                      <option value="<?!= data[i] ?>">
                    <? } ?>
                    </datalist>
                  
                    </div>



<!--------------- Email Select ------------------->

                 <script>
                    function emaildd() {
                    var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
                    console.log(value)
                    }
                  </script>

                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                      <label for="email">email</label>
                      <input type="email" id="input" class="form-control" list="email" name="email" placeholder="Select email" >
                      <datalist id="email"  >
                     <?
                      var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DD");
                      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
                      var myRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C"+lastRow);
                      var data    = myRange.getValues();
                      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
                      <option value="<?!= data[i] ?>">
                    <? } ?>
                    </datalist>
                  
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the value of email to the email's drop down list when a name is selected at the drop down list by searching the value of email using the selected name.
- In your situation, the name and email values are put in the columns "B" and "C" in "DD" sheet, respectively.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to use `addEventListener()` and `google.script.run`. When your current script is used, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. In this case, a function of Google Apps Script is added.

#### HTML&Javascript side:

In your HTML, there are 2 IDs of `input`. So in this modification, those were changed to `input1` and `input2`. Please be careful this.

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="name">name</label>
    <input type="text" id="input1" class="form-control" list="name" name="name" placeholder="Select name">
    <datalist id="name">
      <?
var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DD");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var myRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B"+lastRow);
var data    = myRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
      <option value="<?!= data[i] ?>">
        <? } ?>
    </datalist>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="email">email</label>
    <input type="email" id="input2" class="form-control" list="email" name="email" placeholder="Select email">
    <datalist id="email">
      <?
var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DD");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var myRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C"+lastRow);
var data    = myRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
      <option value="<?!= data[i] ?>">
        <? } ?>
    </datalist>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("change", () => {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(v => {
    document.getElementById("input2").value = v;
  }).getEmailFromName(document.getElementById("input1").value);
});

function namedd() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  console.log(value)
}

function emaildd() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  console.log(value)
}
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please copy and paste this script as Google Apps Script.

```
function getEmailFromName(v) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("DD");
  var values = sheet.getRange("B2:C"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var res = values.filter(([b]) => b == v);
  return res.length > 0 ? res[0][1] : "";
}
```

- When above HTML is opened and you selected the name of drop down list, the drop down list of email is changed by running `google.script.run`.

#### Note:

- If you are opening above HTML with Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version when you modified the script of Web Apps. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.
- In this modified script, it supposes that the each email is the unique value in the emails. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)